# Sonarqube - Caught exception is too generic. Prefer catching specific exceptions to the case that is currently handled

Tags: java, kotlin, sonarqube

Sonar complains when catching the generic type Exception, but I want to catch the exception and log the details(with a specific text that I can search easily in the logs) and re-throw the exception.

I even tried `catch(throwable)` and yet sonar complains with the same message.

What is the solution to pass this sonar check?

Sample code in Kotlin:

```
import mu.KotlinLogging
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

@Aspect
@Component
class LogExceptionAndTimeAspect {
  private val log = KotlinLogging.logger { }

  @Around("apiPackage()")
  fun logExecutionTimeAndExceptionDetails(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any {

    val signature = joinPoint.signature.toShortString()
    val methodArguments = joinPoint.args.joinToString { "${it.javaClass.simpleName}($it)" }
    log.debug("Start....")

    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = try {
      joinPoint.proceed()
    } catch (throwable: Throwable) { //Error is programmatically unrecoverable
      val exceptionDetails = throwable.stackTraceToString().replace(System.lineSeparator(), "")
      log.error {
        "Error that is searchable is $signature, parameters: [$methodArguments], exception is $exceptionDetails"
      }
      log.debug("End....")
      throw throwable
    }

    val duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
    val durationInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration)
    log.info {
      "Aspect: the method $signature, parameters: [$methodArguments], took around $durationInSeconds seconds"
    }
    log.debug("End....")
    return result
  }

}
```

Comment: Catch subclasses of exception. Not the general `Exception`. BTW: Seeing the code would be very helpful

Comment: I dont know and care about what exception it is. I just want to log and rethrow it. A totally valid case especially in aspects etc. I can then search for this specific text in Splunk, Kibana, Grafana etc to create a dashboard. Seems to be a common usecase

Comment: you prefer not to care, but SonarQube is specifically designed to sniff out such "code smells".

Comment: Sonar is a useful tool but it’s also dumb. What about fudging with catch(Error | Exception e){? Or further down to a handful of relevant Exception types. Valid question - upvote.

Comment: Sonar is a tool to help you find (potential) problems in your code. If you think catching `Exception` is appropriate here, then why do you care that Sonar tells you otherwise. It uses heuristics, but those don't always apply. Suppress the rule or this specific reported "violation", and move on.

Comment: Every Sonar warning has a code - I guess that you are getting  RSPEC-2221 (from https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2221  ).  You can put an `@SuppressWarnings(“RSPEC-2221”)` before that `catch` to ignore that specific check before that specific statement.   You should ALWAYS be able to justify each use of @SuppressWarnings (it should NOT be used frequently)

Comment: Mark Rotteveel: I will suppress the rule but before doing that I wanted to check if there is some way I can pass the sonar rule or change my code or something. From the comments, It looks like this is a valid situation to use @SuppressWarnings

Comment: “_I see downvotes but not even a comment about how to handle this_” I’d bet that it’s because you didn’t include the code in question until your edit.

Comment: The solution to pass the check is just as sonar says, don't catch the Exception superclass, catch subclasses. If you don't want to do that then ignore this specific case, sonar lets you ignore individual warnings, or remove the rule from your sonar rules. What are you seeking here, some hack around to trick sonar into not raising the warning?

Comment: I am not sure if its a hack. I was looking for a valid solution since this is a valid case where it is not possible to catch subclasses. Looks like SupressWarning is the right solution for this problem of "log and rethrow"